# Group data by factor and ordered row position

Tags: r, tidyverse

The following code,

```
set.seed(123)
data <- runif(20) 
dummy <- as.data.frame(data)
dummy <- dummy %>% mutate(category = factor(case_when(data < 0.5 ~ 'A', 
                                    data >= 0.5  ~ 'B')))
```

generates a dataframe that looks like this:

```
        data category
1  0.2875775        A
2  0.7883051        B
3  0.4089769        A
4  0.8830174        B
5  0.9404673        B
6  0.0455565        A
7  0.5281055        B
8  0.8924190        B
9  0.5514350        B
10 0.4566147        A
. ...              ...
```

**My problem:**

I want to create a new column called `packet` that creates a new grouping based on the category and the ordered position in the table. It should label the first `packet_size` rows of each category as `packet_num`, then the next `packet_size` rows should be labelled `packet_num + 1`, and so on.

E.g. For `packet_size = 2`, the first 10 rows should look like this:

```
        data category packet
1  0.2875775        A      1
2  0.7883051        B      1
3  0.4089769        A      1
4  0.8830174        B      1
5  0.9404673        B      2
6  0.0455565        A      2
7  0.5281055        B      2
8  0.8924190        B      3
9  0.5514350        B      3
10 0.4566147        A      2
. ...              ...
```

If I filter `dummy` to a single `category`, then I can run the following on the subset, which seems to work:

```
dummy <- dummy %>% add_column(packet=1L)
filtered_dummy <- dummy %>% filter(category=='A')

packet_size <- 2
packet_num <- 1
row_count <- 1
for (i in 1:nrow(filtered_dummy)) {
  filtered_dummy[i, "packet"] <- packet_num

  row_count <- row_count + 1
  if (row_count > packet_size) {
      packet_num <- packet_num + 1
      row_count = 1
  }
}
```

But I am looking for a solution that can automatically run on the full data set, preferably using a Tidyverse solution (i.e. without my loop above). My actual data has the same form as this example but is approx 450000 rows x 90 columns with about 20 different categories in the category column.

I was thinking of some combination of `dplyr::mutate` and `slider::slide` or even somehow just using `dplyr::group_by` and the above looping code but I can't make it work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another option could be:

```
dummy %>%
 group_by(category) %>%
 mutate(packet = ceiling(1:n()/packet_size))

     data category packet
    <dbl> <fct>     <dbl>
 1 0.288  A             1
 2 0.788  B             1
 3 0.409  A             1
 4 0.883  B             1
 5 0.940  B             2
 6 0.0456 A             2
 7 0.528  B             2
 8 0.892  B             3
 9 0.551  B             3
10 0.457  A             2
```

Answer (score 0):

We can create a repeating sequence with a number being repeated for `packet_size` times for each `category`.

```
packet_size <- 2
library(dplyr)

dummy %>%
  group_by(category) %>%
  mutate(packet = rep(seq_len(n()), each = packet_size, length.out = n()))


#    data category packet
#    <dbl> <fct>     <int>
# 1 0.288  A             1
# 2 0.788  B             1
# 3 0.409  A             1
# 4 0.883  B             1
# 5 0.940  B             2
# 6 0.0456 A             2
# 7 0.528  B             2
# 8 0.892  B             3
# 9 0.551  B             3
#10 0.457  A             2
#...
#...
```

---

A `data.table` solution might be helpful since you have lot of rows.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(dummy)[, packet := rep(seq_len(.N), each = packet_size, length.out = .N), 
               category]
```

You could also implement the same logic in base R :

```
dummy$packet <- with(dummy, ave(data, category, FUN = function(x)
               rep(seq_along(x), each = packet_size, length.out = length(x))))
```

Answer (score 0):

We can also use `gl`

```
library(dplyr)
dummy %>%
   group_by(category) %>%
   mutate(packet = as.integer(gl(n(), packet_size, n())))
```

---

Or with `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(dummy)[, packet := as.integer(gl(n(), packet_size, n())), category]
```